# How to get the latest entry per day from an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, date, ecmascript-6

Well, this question might sounds kinda strange, but I'll explain.
I have an array in Javascript that cames from an api like this:

```
[
    {IdLocal: 12, Date: 04-06-2020T15:25},
    {IdLocal: 12, Date: 04-06-2020T10:37},
    {IdLocal: 12, Date: 04-05-2020T12:30},
    {IdLocal: 12, Date: 04-05-2020T13:40}
    {IdLocal: 13, Date: 04-06-2020T15:25},
    {IdLocal: 13, Date: 04-06-2020T10:37},
    {IdLocal: 13, Date: 04-05-2020T12:30},
    {IdLocal: 13, Date: 04-05-2020T13:40}
]
```

And what I want is an way to find the **latest entry per Local, per Day** 
e.g: for the given array I want a response like:

```
[
   {IdLocal: 12, Date: 04-06-2020T15:25}, // the latest in local 12, day 06
   {IdLocal: 12, Date: 04-05-2020T13:40}, // the latest in local 12, day 05
   {IdLocal: 13, Date: 04-06-2020T15:25}, // the latest in local 13, day 06
   {IdLocal: 13, Date: 04-05-2020T13:40}  // the latest in local 13, day 05
]
```

As you can see, I want it to just return the latest entry from each Local in each day.

I think iterating over and over my Array can get really expensive if the array returned became huge.
 I know modern Javascript have really useful array methods as .map and .filter, but I'm a begginer with it.

I was thinking  on .map over each IdLocal and Date but I'm not really sure of how I would do that.

Comment: I think a more verbose example is necessary. I don't understand still what type of date ordering you're asking for here by saying "daily most-recent entry in each local".

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, I think it became confusing... My english is not the best but I tried to make it more compreheensible now. I think now is more visible what I want to filter. I'm starting with stackoverflow, if my question in any manner is wrong or not in accordance with something, just say and I'll try to fix, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: that is a very strange date format.  Far, far more common is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which would use this:

```js
  {IdLocal: 12, Date: "2020-04-06T15:25"},
```

instead of this:

```js
  {IdLocal: 12, Date: "04-06-2020T15:25"},
```

The standard format lets you sort and compare dates in a natural way, and it will be much more interoperable with other systems.  So, if you can switch to this date format, the code isn't too bad:

```js
const extract = items => Object .values (items .reduce (
  (a, {IdLocal, Date, ...rest}) => {
    const key = IdLocal + ':' + Date.slice(0, 10);
    if (! (key in a) || Date > a [key] .Date) {
      a[key] = {IdLocal, Date, ...rest}
    }
    return a
  }, 
  {}
))

const items = [{IdLocal: 12, Date: '2020-04-06T15:25'}, {IdLocal: 12, Date: '2020-04-06T10:37'}, {IdLocal: 12, Date: '2020-04-05T12:30'}, {IdLocal: 12, Date: '2020-04-05T13:40'}, {IdLocal: 13, Date: '2020-04-06T15:25'}, {IdLocal: 13, Date: '2020-04-06T10:37'}, {IdLocal: 13, Date: '2020-04-05T12:30'}, {IdLocal: 13, Date: '2020-04-05T13:40'}]

console .log (extract (items))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We use a straightforward reduction on the list, using a key made up of the `IdLocal` variable and the date portion of the timestamp.  It will generate something like:

```js
{
    "12:2020-04-05": {IdLocal: 12, Date: "2020-04-05T13:40"},
    "12:2020-04-06": {IdLocal: 12, Date: "2020-04-06T15:25"},
    "13:2020-04-05": {IdLocal: 13, Date: "2020-04-05T13:40"},
    "13:2020-04-06": {IdLocal: 13, Date: "2020-04-06T15:25"}
}
```

and then, by calling `Object.values` on this result, we get

```
[
    {IdLocal: 12, Date: "2020-04-05T13:40"},
    {IdLocal: 12, Date: "2020-04-06T15:25"},
    {IdLocal: 13, Date: "2020-04-05T13:40"},
    {IdLocal: 13, Date: "2020-04-06T15:25"}
]
```

Note the use of spreading in `...rest` here.  We need specific access to the `IdLocal` and `Date` properties of your object, but if there are others you need to preserve, this is a useful way to write the code without littering it up with `item.Date` and `item.IdLocal` everywhere.

I personally would write this a little differently, as I prefer working with expressions over statements, and I prefer not to mutate data, even a `reduce` call's accumulator, unless performance tests dictate that not mutating is a bottleneck.  So I might write it like this:

```js
const extract = items => Object .values (items .reduce (
  (a, {IdLocal, Date, ...rest}, _, __, key = IdLocal + ':' + Date.slice(0, 10)) => ({
    ... a,
    [key]: (!a [key] || Date > a[key].Date) ? ({IdLocal, Date, ...rest}) : a [key]
  }), 
  {}
))
```

But it's the same idea in either version.

---

If you are stuck with this date format, it's not horribly more difficult.  I just introduce a function that will format the date, and then use it in several places:

```js
const formatDate = (d) => `${d.slice(6, 10)}-${d.slice(0, 5)}${d.slice(10)}`

const extract = items => Object .values (items .reduce (
  (a, {IdLocal, Date, ...rest}) => {
    const dateStr = formatDate(Date)
    const key = IdLocal + ':' + dateStr.slice(0, 10)
    if (! (key in a) || dateStr > formatDate (a[key] .Date)) {
      a [key] = {IdLocal, Date, ...rest}
    }
    return a
  },
  {}
))

const items = [{IdLocal: 12, Date: '04-06-2020T15:25'}, {IdLocal: 12, Date: '04-06-2020T10:37'}, {IdLocal: 12, Date: '04-05-2020T12:30'}, {IdLocal: 12, Date: '04-05-2020T13:40'}, {IdLocal: 13, Date: '04-06-2020T15:25'}, {IdLocal: 13, Date: '04-06-2020T10:37'}, {IdLocal: 13, Date: '04-05-2020T12:30'}, {IdLocal: 13, Date: '04-05-2020T13:40'}]

console .log (extract (items))
```

This follows the same process, just modified to reformat the date for comparisons.

Comment: Thank you so much, I made some modifications and it fits really well. I'll take note on that usage of .reduce, you teached me something really valuable today :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean sort a JSON array by property?

```js
var items = [
  {IdLocal: 12, Date: "04-06-2020T15:25"},
  {IdLocal: 12, Date: "04-06-2020T10:37"},
  {IdLocal: 12, Date: "04-05-2020T12:30"},
  {IdLocal: 12, Date: "04-05-2020T13:40"},
  {IdLocal: 13, Date: "04-06-2020T15:25"},
  {IdLocal: 13, Date: "04-06-2020T10:37"},
  {IdLocal: 13, Date: "04-05-2020T12:30"},
  {IdLocal: 13, Date: "04-05-2020T13:40"}];
  
  function sortByProperty(property){  
    return function(a,b){  
      if(a[property] > b[property])  
         return 1;  
      else if(a[property] < b[property])  
         return -1;  
    return 0;  
    }  
  }
  
  items.sort(sortByProperty("Date")); //sort according to date
  items.reverse();
  
  console.log(items);
```

Comment: Not at all, I'm sorry if I wrote it in a way that made you misurderstand... I made some edits, now it's probably more comprehensible. What I really want is just the latest entry per day per local. So the latest entry for local 1 in day 1, the latest entry for local 1 in day 2, the latest entry for local 2 in day 1 and etc.

Comment: I think you have to write a function for that. First sort the dates then walk through the array and get the first one and skip the rest till the date is changed.